Vector algebra and limits question
The following question just occurred to me yesterday:
The zero or null vector, $\boldsymbol{\vec 0}$, has neither magnitude nor direction, but for a unit vector $\boldsymbol{\vec r}$ and some scalar multiple $m$
$lim_{ m->0}${$  \frac{m^2\boldsymbol{\vec r}}{|| m^2\boldsymbol{\vec r}||} $}
$= lim_{ m->0} ${ $ \frac {m^2}{ || m^2||}$}
$. \frac {\boldsymbol{\vec r}}{ ||\boldsymbol{\vec r}||} $
$= lim_{ m->0}  \frac {\boldsymbol{\vec r}}{ ||\boldsymbol{\vec r}||}  $
since by L'Hopital's rule the indeterminate form $ \frac {\boldsymbol 0}{\boldsymbol 0} = 1$ in this case.
This means that the vector $m^2\boldsymbol{\vec r}$ always has the direction  $\boldsymbol{\vec r}$, even when $m=0$.
So what can I call this thing,
$lim_{ m->0}$ {  $ m^2\boldsymbol{\vec r} $ } ?
It's definitely not the zero vector,since the zero vector, $\boldsymbol{\vec 0}$, has no direction.
Could I call it the "$\it direction$" or "$\it orientation$" of the unit vector $\boldsymbol{\vec r}$ ?
After all, in the same way a scalar magnitude has no defined direction, the notion of "$\it {direction\  per\  se} $" has no defined magnitude.
It can't be denoted by, $\boldsymbol{\vec 0}$, (that is already taken), could it be denoted by "$ \vec 0_{\boldsymbol{\vec r}}$"  maybe?
Does it ever occur in the literature? If so, what is the symbol for it? It seems like it should be a thing.
I must say though, I rather do like the symbol,"$ \vec 0_{\boldsymbol{\vec r}}$" somehow.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There is a way of talking about "pure directions," ignoring magnitude, and you can interpret this object as one of those. Namely, you can start with the set $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{ 0 \}$ of nonzero vectors and consider the quotient by the action of the positive reals $\mathbb{R}_{+}$ by scaling; that is, you identify $v \sim w$ whenever $v = \lambda w$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$. This says exactly that you identify two nonzero vectors whenever they have the "same direction."
This is a slight variation of the construction of projective space. It can also just be identified with the unit sphere $S^{n-1}$ via the map sending $v \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{ 0 \}$ to $\frac{v}{\| v \|}$, but importantly, the above construction actually shows that it does not depend on a choice of norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (such as the Euclidean norm), and can be defined in terms of the vector space structure only.
Now you can take the limit, not in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but in $S^{n-1}$.

 Incidentally, I would quibble with the claim that the zero vector doesn't have a magnitude. It does have a magnitude, which is zero. But it doesn't have a direction; these are different.


@Quiaochu yeah, I know, zero is a magnitude, I sometimes overlook that, Your answer is beyond me but I select it anyway as its the only one and 'looks as though its correct', But still, is there a 'name' for "a vector of zero magnitude in the direction of r"? and does it have a "symbol"?

@questing-monkey: I would not describe the result as a vector of zero magnitude. You could argue that in some sense the result is a tangent vector at the identity, since these can be thought of as infinitesimal.
